# Print debug log inside App inside a text view

Tags: ios, objective-c, debugging

I am actually looking for a way to display the `debug` log inside the app e.g. inside a `UITextView`. I just want this for debugging while developing not for productive.

I have been searching a while but you just get tips for how to change the layout of the debug log and other stuff but I don't see a way how to access the debug output.

Did anybody already do this or is there any way how to access the debug log? I could imagine Apple just blocked this totally and you cannot access this information.

I would like to get this information:

[image]

---

**UPDATE**

I found something that can [help printing the log](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/03/accessing-the-ios-system-log/). Does somebody know how to include it into a project?

Comment: What do you mean by `debug` log ?

Comment: Given the limited screen space of mobile apps, it's hard to see how this will work effectively.  Surely it's better to spit out debug messages via `NSLog()` (or your favourite logging framework)?

Comment: I would like to get the debug log like you see it in xCode. Would be nice so you can also see the debug while not connected to xCode. I am not talking about crash reports like quincykit, I want just simple logs

Comment: I doubt anyone has done it, as it's a really bad idea.

Comment: @trojanfoe whats exactly the bad idea for seeing a debug log. Of course if you are going to use private api's you have to remove it before uploading, but I am talking about the development time before uploading it.

Comment: As I already mentioned it's screen space.  For a desktop app you can simply use a separate window which won't interfere with the layout of the main app windows.  For mobile apps you cannot do this.  Not only will it interfere with the layout of those windows but it will steal a great deal of space from them.  I am willing to bet nobody has done this successfully.

Comment: I am actually talking just about the app I am inside. And it is also no problem to create a `UIView` which will stay in background and can be faded in every time you want to see the information. Also it shouldn't be a problem to handle this when using `dispatch_async` so it won't result in reduced userinteraction. But even these problems exist, I didn't ask if it causes a problem in displaying the information nor if it is good practice or what ever, I would like to know if possible or not. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code is to save debug log text in text file. This will help in getting debug text in textview also.
Try with this :

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                         NSUserDomainMask, YES);

NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *logPath = [documentsDirectory
                         stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"app.log"];

    freopen([logPath cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding],"a+",stderr);

    NSDictionary *fileAttributes = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:logPath error:nil] ;
    NSNumber *fileSizeNumber = [fileAttributes objectForKey:NSFileSize];

    long long fileSize = [fileSizeNumber longLongValue];

    if(fileSize > 8000000){

        freopen([logPath cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding],"w",stderr);

    }
```

Comment: Yes,this code works for me . you get txt file in iTunes application file sharing tab. for display txt file in iTunes ,you have to add key in target->info as Application supports iTunes file sharing and value is YES. Set "app" as your app name

Answer (score 1):

Every time you NSLog() something, add it (the log string) to an array. Then use UITableView to display logs with manual (button) or automatic update (delegate).

Comment: I thought about this too. Just thought der might be an easier way but I will try to build a class which will manage exactly this! :)